# Fetch failed to <remote>: SSL error - syscall failure

Tags: linux, git, gitkraken

At first, I want to note that git itself works correctly on my Fedora 28 Work station. I mean, I can do clone/fetch/pull/push and any git command in console.

But I faced with couple of problems in GitKraken (v4.0.2).
1) When I use `sudo <gitkraken-root>/gitkraken --proxy-server=<host>:<port>`:
I can not connect to my Bitbucket repository. If I try to perform
Preferences > Authentication > Bitbucket.org > Connect to Bitbucket, then new Firefox window opens but it is empty!

[image: firefox]

Ok, I thought, I have a console. I have cloned the required repository via console (successfully) and opened this repo in GitKraken. Everything's fine for now. But when I try to pull/fetch/push anything, I see next error message: `Fetch failed for origin: SSL error: syscall failure`.

[image: error screen]

2) If I try start GitKrakem without `sudo` then the connection with Bitbucket is established without errors. But I see the same SSL error as in `sudo` case.

Guys, please, could anyone help with this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't :( The problem is still actual on my Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [GitUp issue](https://github.com/git-up/GitUp/issues/127) where a similar error occured:

> Make sure your SSH private keys are either in ~/.ssh/ or better added
>   to the SSH agent, which you can do with ssh-add -K
>   ~/.ssh/my_private_key.

Maybe this can solve your problem as well?

Comment: Actually, you can tell GK where you keep your keys: `Preferences -> Authentication -> General` lets you set the paths for your private and public SSH key files.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I agree with @kowsky - "Use local SSH agent" option is ticked in my GK.
But I do not use SSH key for this repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because my repo URL has been changed. I changed repo URL in the git config file at the local machine and it works as expected.